# .htaccess : How To Block queries starting with /?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website is hosted on WordPress and since yesterday I am continuously getting bad requests which are causing to down my website. Website showing "resource limit is reached" and in my Cpanel entry process 40/40 and CPU usage 100/100.

**I am getting queries from lots of different ips at same time and not able to block them.**

**here are queries types-**

```
myurl/?tie=strange
myurl/?connect=once
myurl/?me=sight
myurl/?yard=gentle
myurl/?man=are
myurl/?man=are
myurl/?may=dance
myurl/?chief=add
myurl/?we=true
```

**Here are referring urls -**

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=your
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=world

http: //www. zahnarzt-buhl.de/praxis/plugins/content/plugin_googlemap2_proxy.php?url=near

http: //www .w3.org/services/tidy?docAddr=measure
```

When I am blocking "?" (punctuation mark)in the .htaccess file then my site works fine except URLs containing punctuation mark.

**I have added these lines in .htaccess file**

- RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?
- RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

I want to only block forward slash and the question mark together ("/?") so that if request URLs contain /? together then block it and if only question mark? found then allow.

Comment: how to find malware in my website?

Comment: You can't really block that as that would prevent your website from receiving query strings. You could filter on a combination of referrer and query string tho.

Comment: @RamaNazi Start by talking to your hosting provider and see what information on the issue they can provide u with or if they can do anything. Some providers will even place your site behind a filtering among other options. That is assuming that really is an attack. Also blocking the querystring will potentially retain your site from properly functioning, don't think its a proper solution. At the very least they will tell you what is consuming all your plan, from there you could try to hire an expert to look at your site and properly advise you on what path to take.